# Calculate whether the following sequence diverges or converges.

Tags: limits

Could someone please confirm my steps below, I am not sure if I have done this right.
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(n+3)^{n+1}} $$

For large values of n:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{(n+3)^{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{n^{n+1}} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0 $$ 
Hence the sequence converges.
Is this correct and if so, is there a better way to show this? (This is for an exam so I am not sure if this is enough working out for this question)

Comment: Write the terms as ${1\over n+3}{1\over\Bigl(1+{3\over n}\Bigr)^{n}}$.

Comment: Ahh perfect, exactly what I was looking, Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Actually, your solution is better; but use the Squeeze Theorem. ($0\le {n^n\over (n+3)^{n+1}}\le{1\over n}$.)

Comment: Good idea, so is it fine to say n^n/(4n)^(n+1)< The sequence < 1/n (OOps just saw your result)